# How to execute a pile of commands one by one and supply input for each one in python?

Tags: python

I wish to execute a pile of commands such as `python do_it.py file_a`, `python do_it.py file_b`, etc, in python, for example,

```
for fl in ['file_a', 'file_b']:
    cmd = 'python do_it.py {}'.format(fl)
    os.system(cmd)
```

However, each run will require std input from console, and I need to type `Y` or `N` in, then `enter` to get each continuing execution.

What's the best way to make all these automatic, if I know the input to the console will be all `Y` anyway?

Comment: Under Unixes, check the [`yes`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html) utility. Then run your command as `os.system('yes | '+cmd)`

Comment: Use `subprocess.run()` instead of `os,system()`, and pass in `input="Y\n"` or similar.  But since you seem to be in control of `do_it.py`, why not simply change that file to not require input in the first place?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from doing `import do_it`?